# Show button after click on my pub

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a button after the person has clicked on my advertisement.
Currently it does not work. The button appears and disappears immediately and the ad does not start. thank you in advance for your help

```
<div id="pub" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" style="color:black;" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="SEND">
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('pub').style.display = 'block';"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.publicity.com/8868-728x90.js"></script>
</button>
```

**PUB :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.publicity.com/8868-728x90.js">
```

Comment: Where is the Advertisement ? Is it a separate Div. You only have a button visible as per your HTML.

Comment: @Agalo I modified my ad

Comment: I am still not clear what does your advertisement do and what is the js file at http://www.publicity.com/8868-728x90.js doing ?

Comment: @Agalo It just shows a pub

Comment: Can not anyone help me?